# I am trying to create a program that asks for your age and a password in Python

Tags: python

I believe this will work but it keeps giving me an error message in the last line of the code for invalid syntax and I am not sure why looking for help.

```
password=123

ask=raw_input("What is the password")

try:

    while ask=="123":
        age=int(raw_input("What is your age"))
        if age >= 18: 
            print("You are able to vote in the United States!")
        else:
            print("You are not able to vote in the United States.")
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? 2.x or 3.x? Before 3.x `print` was not used as a function. Try `print "You are not..."`

Comment: Obviously 2.x (`raw_input` was removed in Python 3), but that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working version of you code after some minor changes:

```
password = "123"
ask = raw_input("What is the password?\n")

if ask == password:
    age = int(raw_input("What is your age?\n"))
    if age >= 18: 
        print("You are able to vote in the United States!")
    else:
        print("You are not able to vote in the United States.")
```

Comment: Could you describe, what you have changed?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I've just compiled it, I don't see a reason for a downvote.

Comment: @LutzHorn removed `try` and changed `while` to `if`.

Comment: `age` is an integer, and only Unicode objects have an `isnumeric()` method. So I very much doubt that you were able to get this to run...

Comment: I've corrected this one before your last comment. Still, you've commented that it doesn't compile, not that it doesn't run. And it isn't right to downvote an answer just because yours wasn't accepted.

Comment: Using `isnumeric()` on an int isn't a `SyntaxError`, it's an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Oh, OK, I see it now. I tried `123.isnumeric()` where it's a SyntaxError, but on a variable, it's an AttributeError, of course. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a `try` statement always needs an `except` clause to be syntactically valid.

In your case, the `try` statement doesn't quite make sense (as do some other parts of your program), so you should just remove it and outdent the `while` block accordingly.

It *would* make sense to guard against non-integer inputs, but if that was your intention, you should place it in that position:

```
password = "123"
ask = raw_input("What is the password")
if ask == password:
    while True:
        try:
            age = int(raw_input("What is your age? "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "Please enter an integer number!"

    if age >= 18: 
        print("You are able to vote in the United States!")
    else:
        print("You are not able to vote in the United States.")
```